# Как узнать края окна win32 в С++ на visual studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-c++, окно

Здравствуйте я начал осваивать C++ примерно месяц назад. Пока что разобрался только с консолью и захотел сделать нормальное приложение, но я совсем не понимаю как там всё устроено. И у меня вопрос как узнать **края** или **центр** приложения?

Comment: А что понимается под "*края или центр приложения*"? Или имеется в виду координаты окна приложения? Если речь про окно, то его размер и координаты можно узнать функцией `GetWindowRect`.

Comment: @freim спасибо это как раз то что я искал.